# Non-transactional trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

As far as I know, if we try to perform some writing operation for the table having some trigger on that operation and the trigger fail the write operation will fail either. It looks like both operation are being performing in the same transaction. But is it possible to do the following:

- If the trigger fail due to some reason (throwing exception or something else):

  - write a log entry and allow the write operation to be completed succfully if it can.

Comment: You are looking for "autonomous transactions" which are currently not possible in Postgres without a workaround. The workaround is to do the logging through a DBLink connection.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, but is somehting like that currently possible in postgresql? I mean, I need to perform ON UPDATE trigger-like writing in the table or write a log entry if it fail. Is that possible?

Comment: As I said: only if you do the update through a DBLink. Search for "postgres autonomous transaction"

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you split it into 2 procedures and do the write as a separate procedure?  This would be my suggestion given the info that you have posted, if you want more we need more info ***(DB vendor and version, and post your code)***

Comment: I've specified the vendor. What code are you asking about? The question is about triggers in general.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the tag with Postgre, I just read your post.

Comment: Also, the code *is* important if you want advice on how to break it down.  Without looking at what you are doing, I can't suggest a way to do it so that you guarantee part of it runs successfully regardless of the rest of it.  Generally, I still say use 2 transactions

Answer (score 1):

Errors raised within the trigger can be trapped by adding an [`EXCEPTION` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) to the trigger code. The exception block can contain a [`RAISE LOG`/`RAISE WARNING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) statement to write a message to the server log (though this depends on the [configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN)). The operation which fired the trigger will still be able to complete successfully.

For example, if your trigger body is:

```
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t VALUES (new.id);
  RETURN NULL;
END
$$
```

then you might want something like:

```
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t VALUES (new.id);
  RETURN NULL;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN unique_violation THEN
    RAISE LOG 'Duplicate ID %', new.id;
    RETURN NULL;
END
$$
```